# WebDAV by Apache behind NginX Reverse Proxy

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, centos, webdav

I'm having some trouble adding a Network Location from windows to my webdav directory. My setup is that it hits NginX which reverse proxies to httpd on Centos. WebDAV works fine from a browser or a linux webdav client, just not from windows.  I have also tried MyWorkDrive and BitKinex clients and they will not connect either.

From windows 'Add Network Location', I get the following error "***The folder you entered does not appear to be valid. Please choose another.***"

In my access log, I get:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2019:06:46:32 -0700] "OPTIONS /webdav HTTP/1.0" 401 381 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18363"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2019:06:46:32 -0700] "OPTIONS /webdav HTTP/1.0" 401 381 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18363"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2019:06:46:32 -0700] "OPTIONS /webdav HTTP/1.0" 401 381 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18363"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2019:06:46:32 -0700] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18363"
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Dec/2019:06:46:33 -0700] "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.0" 405 236 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18363"
```

Nothing shows up in my error log.

My virtual host file has:

```
<Directory /srv/apps/distributive/public/webdav>
            DAV On
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "webdav"
            AuthUserFile /srv/apps/distributive/public/webdav/.htpasswd
            Require valid-user
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My NginX conf contains:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      $backend_protocol://$backend_host:$backend_port;
}
```

Which uses this conf for variables:

```
map $host $backend_protocol {
    default    http;
}
map $host $backend_host {
    default    127.0.0.1;
}
map $host $backend_port {
    default    81;
}
```

Lastly, my httpd -M shows the webdav modules loaded:

```
[root@MyHost]# httpd -M | grep dav
 dav_module (shared)
 dav_fs_module (shared)
 dav_lock_module (shared)
```